# При отправке через скрипт Mailwizz письмо приходит иероглифами

Tags: php, email

может кто то сталкивался.
пользуюсь скриптом Mailwizz для отправки email сообщений.
В редакторе писем все нормально отображается

[image: нормальный текст в редакторе]

А когда приходит письмо на почту, то оно приходит в виде иероглифов.

[image: кракозябры в письме]

Подскажите в чем проблема, спасибо

Comment: Здесь есть свой сервис для картинок, поэтому не рекомендуется использовать сторонние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте кодировку исходящего сообщения, она должна настраиваться
2. Лучше использовать PHPMailer, если есть такая возможность, хотя, надо полагать, Mailwizz был куплен?

Comment: да mailwizz куплен, лицензионный. а где смотреть эту кодировку? я еще новичок просто

Comment: @Бабуин, раз вы его купили, то автор/продавец должен поддержку оказывать и помогать решать возникшие проблемы с его продуктом.

Comment: да он в принципе молодец помогает, но в данном случае, говорит что проблема не в скрипте. в общем пытаюсь решить вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится, но я решил проблему следующим образом.
DaemonHK был прав, просто я же до конца не понимал где это править.
Подсказал разработчик.

Надо создать шаблон, в котором указать кодировку UTF-8, и использовать его при создании письма.

[image: указание кодировки письма]

Но это не все, после этого иероглифы все равно остались. Опытным путем я выяснил, что когда прикрепляю картинку, то приходят иероглифы, а если просто текст, то все ровно.

[image: установка запрета прикрепления изображений к письму]

При создании сообщения, просто надо выбрать галочку НЕТ как показано на скрине выше и все будет гуд.

Comment: А если потребуется вставить изображение?) Может при добавлении как раз в шаблоне и "портится" кодировка?

Comment: там на скрине я показал, что когда нажимаешь не вставлять изображение, а подгружать. то есть в CK Editor также все вставляется изображение, просто методом подгрузки.